# pdfLaTeX producing blank output

Tags: color

Very odd situation. Can't give an MWE as I am using a custom class that I wrote (I cannot distribute it publicly because of the rights for some of the code I have included for logos, etc. - not easy to remove, its programmatic and distributed).

This class has been producing perfect PDFs for months now. As far as I am concerned, it still does. However, several of my colleagues complain that they are getting basically blank pages.

Almost as if I have white text on white background.

I have checked the PDF - fonts are embedded.

The only odd thing that sounds like any of this is that when I use LaTeXIt of late, I am using \color{white} to produce white text. But then, settings for LaTeXIt cannot mess up MacTeX on my mac. At least logically.

To be clear, we are talking about different documents in a different applications being possibly affected in this fashion. Boggles the mind if true. Further, my latest use of \color{} was a \color{yellow}.
Another possible issue is that I am stuck on the old version (MacTeX 2013) as the installers for MacTeX 2014 do not work on Yosemite (which I was foolish enough to upgrade to).

I can't expect you to give me a neatly packaged solution given the sketchy description provided, but if you could drop some hints, it may help me debug this.

To reiterate - I do not see any problems with the PDFs I produce (in Preview or Adobe Reader). Some people I email them to, do.

Comment: `\color{white}` will generate all white, but `\textcolor{white}{This is white text}` will only use the white color for *This is white text* ... You should use `\color` with care

Comment: A little off-topic comment: You have posted some questions and there are (good) answers to them, but you nearly accepted none of them.

Comment: @cfr: Sorry, don't get you right now

Comment: you need to work out why it is white (pdftools could help) either there is no text in the pdf, or it is white or it's using a font that the renderer can't see. Your comment on Christian's answer makes me suspect the last of these.

Comment: Could you clarify: are your colleagues viewing PDFs produced on your machine? Or are they using your custom class to produce the problematic PDFs? Also, what is the relationship between your use of LaTeXit and your documents? Are you including images from the former in the latter? Or what?

Comment: @cfr - I generate and email them PDF documents, which they view on their own machines. No other relationship.

Comment: @cfr: I see... typical 'German' error: `nearly` could mean `almost` in German translation ;-)

Comment: @cfr: 'You accepted only a few of them' :-) ... another off-topic comment ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Shall we tidy up?

Comment: @cfr: No, I am looking for an argument ;-)

Comment: Check (with pffonts utility or acrobat fonts menu that you have embedded the fomts in the pdf, if the pdf is refering to external non standard fonts it wont work unless you have the fonts installed on the reading machine.

Comment: The fonts are embedded. Its not a fonts issue. I have been using this for months without any complaints. Whatever went screwy, went screwy on my machine.

Comment: These are standard fonts. Nothing non-standard about helvetica, is there?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `\color` should be done with care, as it changes the textcolor until another `\color` command follows or it is done within a group. The usage of `\textcolor{white}{Text to be shown}` is strongly encouraged.

In this demo document, I used an 'open' `\color{red}` command in order to show, that the red color is still active, although a `{\color{blue}...}` command has been used in between.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\color{white}
You won't see this on a white page
\clearpage
\pagecolor{black}
Now you will see the text
\color{red}

\textcolor{white}{Only this is white}
{\color{blue}{And this is limited blue text}} % Grouped 

And this is red
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But we are talking about two different applications, aren't we (LaTeXIt in one case, and my tex editor in another case)? Different documents, etc. Is the use of \color{} persistent in this pernicious a manner? I just found out that if I "print" the offending PDF (which looks perfectly fine to me) to another PDF, the recipient can see it perfectly well.

Comment: even more interesting if you put `\color{white}` in the preamble, as then in addition the document default colour is set to white so page head and foot and other "normalised" areas are white as well.

Comment: @user2751530: As you hide your 'class' I can't say what goes wrong, but `\color{white}` seems to be faulty. That was my guess, but there might be other issues